# Apply different tax rate based on user role

Tags: php, woocommerce, role, tax

I use WooCommerce and Members plugin. I have created special tax rate classes (CustomerTaxExemptTaxClass & CustomerPSTExemptTaxClass for customers who can be tax exempt or pay a certain tax only (pay only PST tax in Canada). I have created two new roles with the members plugin: Customer Tax Exempt & Customer PST Exempt.

I have added the following code into my Child Theme functions.php file, however it does not work.

```
/* APPLY DIFFERENT TAX RATE BASED ON CUSTOMER USER ROLE */
/* special tax rate: zero if role: Customer Tax Exempt */
function CustomerTaxExemptTaxClass( $tax_class, $product ) {
  global $current_user;

    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('customer_tax_exempt')) {
        $tax_class = 'CustomerTaxExemptClass';
    }               

  return $tax_class;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'CustomerTaxExemptTaxClass', 1, 2 );

/* special tax rate: charge only GST if role: customer_pst_exempt */
function CustomerPSTExemptTaxClass( $tax_class, $product ) {
  global $current_user;

    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('customer_pst_exempt')) {
        $tax_class = 'CustomerPSTExemptClass';
    }               

  return $tax_class;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'CustomerPSTExemptTaxClass', 1, 2 );
```

I used a suggested tax exempt code snippet, but I'm not PHP expert by any means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Lyse

Comment: Try adding the tag 'php' to get attention from users that follow the php tag

Comment: That hook isn't going to work since it's deprecated since version 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to make this logic work for quite some days. There are 3 or 4 snippets online that are not properly coded. Some even cause big conflict with analytics and Jetpack.

Essentially none of the pieces of code I found mentioned the need to adding a capability into the user role so that the logic can detect it easily. In this case I added a custom capability called "tax_exempt" in the new user role I created.

```
add_filter( 'init', 'make_customer_tax_exempt' );
function make_customer_tax_exempt() {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin() && !is_null(wc()->customer)) {
        $tax_exempt = current_user_can( 'tax_exempt');
        wc()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt($tax_exempt);
    }
}
```